# Facebook Android SDK 3.0 Login Button does not save my session

Tags: android, facebook, session, sdk

I'm trying Facebook Android SDK 3.0 tutorial but I'm facing a problem. When I clicked the login button and logged in using my facebook account, im expecting to see my button's text to change to logout as what the tutorial (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) states but it did not happen. I added log to see if it passes by onActivityResult as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260555/facebook-android-sdk-3-0-always-returns-opening-when-logging-in) question. Here's my log:

```
MainFragment   Unknown State: OPENING
MainFragment   onActivityResult
MainFragment   Logged out...
```

Please help. I don't know where did I get wrong and what to do next?

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");     
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown state: " + state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);      

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);    

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution. The keytool's hash is not working for me. I followed Karim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621688/always-getting-session-stateclosed-login-failed-tokenaccesstoken-tokenacces/15059172#15059172) and it worked for me. Place this in your MainActivity onCreate() method and of course change to your package name. Copy the generated hash and use that instead of the keytool's hash.

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("<your_package_name>",  PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
```

Comment: Hey @user9507 I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Why would this be happening?